# Overwrite Copy Text operation from a QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt, clipboard, copy-paste

I have a `QTreeWidget` where I would to overwrite the Copy Text (ctrl+c) from the `QTreeWidgetItem`.

The default behaviour is to copy the `text` from the selected column, but I'd like to update the values with more information that I have on the background.

Is there a native way of doing it without capturing the `ctrl+c` with a `keyPressEvent` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following approach to store your own stuff in clipboard without overriding `QWidget::keyPressEvent()`:

```
// Assuming tree widget already exists.
auto shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+C"), treeWidget);
QObject::connect(shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, [treeWidget] () {
    auto selected = treeWidget->selectedItems();
    // Get only first selected item's text.
    if (selected.size() > 0)
    {
        QClipboard *clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
        clipboard->setText(QString("Custom clipboard text: %1").arg(selected.at(0)->text(0)));
    }
});
```

In the code I used `QShortcut` to handle `Ctrl+C` key sequence and store selected tree widget item's text (customized) into the clipboard.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that the default context for the `QShortcut` is `Qt::WindowShortcut`, which can be a bit "infectious" and have surprising results when it picks up the copy operation when another widget has focus. 
if the goal is to give the tree widget a copy override, you can use the `Qt::WidgetShortcut` instead